# Quitar doble fila dentro una tabla CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3, scss, table

Cuando tengo algun espacio automaticamente la tabla me la hace dos filas, alguna manera para que la fila este estatica y ajustandose al ancho de la informacion,
evito usar anchos estaticos  como:

```
with:200px
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías ajustar el ancho de la tabla para que todos los campos puedan cupir bien en su espacio o asignarle un width con porcentaje a estas columnas. Yo siempre les Asigno ancho fijo para cuando tengo esos casos

Comment: Con una imagen es difícil saber lo que estás haciendo, por favor comparte un poco de tu código para ver qué clases o propiedades estás aplicando a la tabla. ¿Cómo estás manejando el ancho de tu tabla, por ejemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con

```css
white-space: nowrap;
```